# Adding Interfaces to DataContext Classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-To-SQL and I would like to attach an interface to each of my entities.

I can edit the designer.cs file and accomplish this.

However, when I make a changes to the dbml through the UI it rewrites the whole designer.cs and I lose my changes.

Am I just going to have to deal with it, or is there a way to get around it?

I am doing this in the designer.cs file(the IMatchable is a custom interface of mine):

```
public partial class Error : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged, IMatchable
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't edit the designer file; the beauty of partial classes is that you can create a **separate** file with **just**

```
public partial class Error : IMatchable
{ }
```

(assuming that we are using implicit interface implementaion by virtue of having properties that match the required interface)

Small word of caution though: if you are using VS2008 and you have `MyClasses.dbml` and `MyClasses.designer.cs`, do **not** call this file `MyClasses.cs` - there is a bug in VS2008 that makes this a nuisance (you have to keep moving the `using` directives inside the namespace, or the code-generator breaks) - fixed in VS2010 though.

Also, if it was a *single* interface, that **every** type in your model implemented, you can cheat by specifying that at the object base-type in the DBML. The designer doesn't show this option, but if you edit the DBML manually it works fine.

Comment: I tried that, but I left off the Interfaces it puts on there =(. I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: @Blankasaurus - if those interfaces were already in the other half of the partial class, you don't need to re-add them. If it didn't pick them up, try checking you are in the right namespace, etc.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. When I tried it before it was actually me failing at namespacing and not the lack of those interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for this, losing my own interfaces every time I touched the LINQ2SQL designer was driving me crazy.